# Android: passing a OnClickListener into an adapter

Tags: java, android

**Question:**

How do we pass a OnLongClickListener into an adapter when setting it in the activity?

**Adapter's constructor:**

```
public Activity mcontext;
public View.OnLongClickListener LongClicking;

public SubjectsAdapter(Activity context, View.OnLongClickListener longClick) {
    this.mcontext = context;
    this.LongClicking = longClick;
}
```

**In the activity:**

```
adapter = new SubjectsAdapter(this, /*A OnLongClickListener here */ );
```

I know this is probably a dense question, I'm relatively new to android

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can pass it as an anonymous class

```
adapter = new SubjectsAdapter(this, new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            //do your stuff
        }
    } );
```

But how do you register this callback for a particular view? I'd suggest to register it for the view, which is interested in this callback with [setOnLongClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnLongClickListener(android.view.View.OnLongClickListener)) instead of passing it to the adapter (but it depends on your app).

```
yourview.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            //do your stuff
        }
    });
```

Comment: woudn't that first option be the same as setting the OnLongCLickListener in the adapter's ViewHolder? (I'm using a RecyclerView)

Comment: Yes, you can do that. You can also implement `View.OnLongClickListener` in your particular `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`. See this [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30078344/handle-on-item-long-click-on-recycler-view) or this [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945078/onlongitemclick-in-recyclerview/27945635#27945635)