# View cannot be converted to MotionEvent and MotionEvent cannot be converted to View

Tags: java, android

plz help getting error View cannot be converted to MotionEvent and MotionEvent cannot be converted to View ..

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;



   public class RecyclerTouchListener implements OnItemTouchListener {
    private ClickListener clickListener;
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public interface ClickListener {
        void onClick(View view, int i);

        void onLongClick(View view, int i);
    }

    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean z) {
    }

    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    }

    public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
        this.gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                return true;
            }

            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                motionEvent = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());
                if (motionEvent != null && clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener.onLongClick(motionEvent, recyclerView.getChildPosition(motionEvent));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        View findChildViewUnder = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());
        if (!(findChildViewUnder == null || this.clickListener == null || this.gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent) == null)) {
            this.clickListener.onClick(findChildViewUnder, recyclerView.getChildPosition(findChildViewUnder));
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

error list in single file

1-incomparable types: boolean and `<null>`

2-incompatible types:  cannot be converted to boolean

3-incompatible types: View cannot be converted to MotionEvent

4-incompatible types: MotionEvent cannot be converted to View

don't know how I can solve this problem.

Thank you in advance for your help

I hope to be clear, I'm sorry if there are mistakes

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a **specific problem or error** and the **shortest code necessary** to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.* For more information on how to ask a good question, consider [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour/), or checking out the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

On `motionEvent = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder`

[`findChildViewUnder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#findChildViewUnder(float,%20float)) method returns a View. A [`MotionEvent` is a type of `InputEvent` not a `View`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent)

---

`this.gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent) == null` isn't a valid comparison because a boolean primitive can never be null, only true of false if the touch is intercepted.

Similarly, `onInterceptTouchEvent` cannot `return null`

---

You should be using `setOnClickListener` rather than using a GestureDetector and manually invoking `onClick` from the listener

- [Handle on item long click on recycler view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30078344/handle-on-item-long-click-on-recycler-view)
- https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/recyclerview-part-1-fundamentals-for-listview-experts/

Comment: what i have to do plz let me know. to get ride of this problem..plz

Comment: Rewrite this whole class following the links provided

Comment: Basically, your `public interface ClickListener` is not needed, and should be removed. And the GestureDetector isn't needed either for finding click events.