# OnItemLongClick doesn't work in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have problem with RecyclerView, because when I long press on view, it results simple click. This is simple implementation of long click. Of course in my code I set this listeners to my Adapter.

```
public class HomeListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeListAdapter<P>.ViewHolder> {

    OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener;
    OnItemLongClickListener mItemLongClickListener;

    public HomeListAdapter() {
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {


        public ViewHolder(View itemView, int viewType) {
            super(itemView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mItemClickListener != null) {
                mItemClickListener.onItemClick(itemView, getPosition());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            if (mItemLongClickListener != null) {
                mItemLongClickListener.onItemLongClick(itemView, getPosition());
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

        public void setOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
            this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
        }

        public void setOnItemLongClickListener(final OnItemLongClickListener mItemLongClickListener) {
            this.mItemLongClickListener = mItemLongClickListener;
        }
    }


public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}

public interface OnItemLongClickListener {
    void onItemLongClick(View view, int position);
}


public class HomeListOnItemClickListener implements OnItemClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        Log.d("Test", "Click");
    }
}

public class HomeListOnItemLongClickListener implements OnItemLongClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {
        Log.d("Test", "Long Click");
    }
}
```

Every help will be appreciated.

Comment: Don't you have to do itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this) ?

Comment: Of course. Thank you so much.

Comment: Check out this answer [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945078/onlongitemclick-in-recyclerview ]

Comment: @ThirdMartian kindly check my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() 
 {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

     Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Long Click" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     return true;

    }
 });
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html

> public void setOnLongClickListener (View.OnLongClickListener l)
>
> Added in API level 1 Register a callback to be invoked when this view
>   is clicked and held. If this view is not long clickable, it becomes
>   long clickable.