# Single and Double Tap on recycleview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a problem with my code, when i do a single or double tap on item both onDoubleTap and onSingleTapConfirmed are actived while i dont have problem with onLongClick.

In my activity:

```
mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getContext(), mRecyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSingleTapConfirmed(View view, int position) {}
            @Override
            public void onDoubleTap(View view, int position){}
            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {}
        }));
```

In my custom listener class:

```
public class RecyclerTouchListener implements recyclerView.OnItemTouchListener{
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private ClickListener clickListener;

    public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                }
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {

                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

        View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            clickListener.onSingleTapConfirmed(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
        }
        return false;
    }
    public interface ClickListener {
        void onSingleTapConfirmed(View view, int position);
        void onDoubleTap(View view, int position);
        void onLongClick(View view, int position);
    }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this listener as `OnDoubleClickListener.java`:

```
public abstract class OnDoubleClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    private final int doubleClickTimeout;
    private Handler handler;

    private long firstClickTime;

    public OnDoubleClickListener() {
        doubleClickTimeout = ViewConfiguration.getDoubleTapTimeout();
        firstClickTime = 0L;
        handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

        if (now - firstClickTime < doubleClickTimeout) {
            handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
            firstClickTime = 0L;
            onDoubleClick(v);
        } else {
            firstClickTime = now;
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    onSingleClick(v);
                    firstClickTime = 0L;
                }
            }, doubleClickTimeout);
        }
    }

    public abstract void onDoubleClick(View v);

    public abstract void onSingleClick(View v);

    public void reset() {
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    }
}
```

and then add `ItemClickSupport.java`

```
public class ItemClickSupport {
    private final RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;
    private OnDoubleClickListener mOnDoubleClickListener = new OnDoubleClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDoubleClick(View v) {
            if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
                RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = mRecyclerView.getChildViewHolder(v);
                mOnItemClickListener.onItemDoubleClicked(mRecyclerView, holder.getAdapterPosition(), v);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSingleClick(View v) {
            if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
                RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = mRecyclerView.getChildViewHolder(v);
                mOnItemClickListener.onItemClicked(mRecyclerView, holder.getAdapterPosition(), v);
            }
        }
    };

    private RecyclerView.OnChildAttachStateChangeListener mAttachListener
            = new RecyclerView.OnChildAttachStateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildViewAttachedToWindow(View view) {
            if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
                view.setOnClickListener(mOnDoubleClickListener);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildViewDetachedFromWindow(View view) {

        }
    };

    private ItemClickSupport(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        mRecyclerView = recyclerView;
        mRecyclerView.setTag(R.id.item_click_support, this);
        mRecyclerView.addOnChildAttachStateChangeListener(mAttachListener);
    }

    public static ItemClickSupport addTo(RecyclerView view) {
        ItemClickSupport support = (ItemClickSupport) view.getTag(R.id.item_click_support);
        if (support == null) {
            support = new ItemClickSupport(view);
        }
        return support;
    }

    public static ItemClickSupport removeFrom(RecyclerView view) {
        ItemClickSupport support = (ItemClickSupport) view.getTag(R.id.item_click_support);
        if (support != null) {
            support.detach(view);
        }
        return support;
    }

    public ItemClickSupport setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mOnItemClickListener = listener;
        return this;
    }

    private void detach(RecyclerView view) {
        view.removeOnChildAttachStateChangeListener(mAttachListener);
        view.setTag(R.id.item_click_support, null);
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v);
        void onItemDoubleClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v);
    }
}
```

and use it :

```
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),
                2, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

      // Make sure your recyler view adapter implements getItemAt(position), which return the item from the dataset placed at position
      // in this case I use getProductId() from my POJO Product class

        ItemClickSupport.addTo(mRecyclerView)
                .setOnItemClickListener(new ItemClickSupport.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v) {
                        Log.d("ITEM CLICK", "Item single clicked " + mRecyclerViewAdapter.getItemAt(position).getProductId());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onItemDoubleClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v) {
                        Log.d("ITEM CLICK", "Item double clicked " + mRecyclerViewAdapter.getItemAt(position).getProductId());
                    }
                });
```

[source](https://www.littlerobots.nl/blog/Handle-Android-RecyclerView-Clicks/)

or check [this gist](https://gist.github.com/beraldofilippo/d8d2404bc6f4217fd1a76166cf23e2d0)

Comment: Thanks, everything works. Last thing, how can I also insert the longPress listener?

Comment: if works you can accept this answer and take upvote! please.
also for answering your question: you can implemented separate from `ItemClickSupport` like https://stackoverflow.com/a/27945635 or can add longPressed feature to this `ItemClickSupport`!

Comment: @beigirad what is `item_click_support`? Where to add that?

Comment: You also need to define R.id.item_click_support using ids.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="item_click_support" type="id" />
</resources>

Comment: How do you add the getItemAt(position) method in the recycler view? could you please give one example?